# Getting the name of a link from a html web site using Python

Tags: python, html

```
<a class="inst" href="http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=9987529074833218" target="9987529074833218">كشت و صنعت آبشيرين</a>
```

I need to fetch the name of the link(`"كشت و صنعت آبشيرين"`). I can fetch the `href` and the `target`, but I don't know how to get the name.

Below you will find a piece of code that I used to get the link and target to write on a text file. Can you please help me extract the name also.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    Href_q.write(link.get('href')+ '\t' + link.get('target') + '\n')
Href_q.close()
```

Comment: Access `link.text` ? (or it might be `link.string` - one of the two...)

Comment: Href_q.write(link.get('href')+ '\t' + link.get('target') + '\t' + link.text() + '\n') is not working

Comment: Did you try `link.string` or possibly `link.get_text()` depending on the structure of your document and what you want?

Comment: none of them are working

Answer (score 0):

Here after is the code to your solution

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = '<a class="inst" href="http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=9987529074833218" target="9987529074833218">كشت و صنعت آبشيرين</a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(source,features="lxml")

print(soup.find('a').text)
```

output:

```
                                                                     كشت و صنعت آبشيرين
```

Comment: is it possible to put a variable as href in source ?

Comment: Yes... just add link.text